# UITableView slide not editable row with editable rows Xcode iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I'm developing an iPhone app and I have one problem. I have a UITableView with a few editable rows(

```
 -(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{ )
```

and one not editable row. If I click edit, the editable rows slide a bit to the right and there is a red round button at the left of it, but the not editable row doesn't slide at all. Is there a way to also slide it to the right but without the red button at the left? It doesn't look that nice at the moment. I hope someone can help me with this:)

Comment: Do you use custom cells, or simply customizing a built-in one?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it's a good idea to change the default behavior of the tableView.
But if you really want to, you could e.g. use indentation.

```
// Might be target of button
- (void) setEditingMode
{
    tableView.editing = YES;
    [tableView reloadData];
}

// Might be target of button
- (void) resetEditingMode
{
    tableView.editing = NO;
    [tableView reloadData];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell* cell = ...;
    ....
    Boolean cellIsEditable = ...;
    if( tableView.editing && !cellIsEditable )
    {
        cell.indentationWidth = ...; // (please experiment to find the exact value)
        cell.indentationLevel = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.indentationLevel = 0;
    } 
}
```

Comment: oh sorry I forgot to say that it is a grouped tableView. but this will only slide the text to the right, but the cell is still full size:S

Comment: I solved the problem myself:) but still thanks for your help!:)

Comment: @kjeldGr - what was the solution? if you wish, you can answer your own question (and mark it as an answer using the tick underneath the vote count) so it will help others that stumble on this question

Answer (score 0):

Subclass the UITableViewCell and slide the uneditable row yourself.

```
@interface MyHistoryTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@end

@implementation MyHistoryTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

#define CELL_SLIDE_WIDTH    32  // found empirically
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    if ( self.editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone ) { // not editable
        CGRect frame = self.frame;
        UITableView *tableView = ((UITableView *)(self.superview));
        if ( tableView.editing ) { // going to editing mode
            frame.origin.x = CELL_SLIDE_WIDTH;
            frame.size.width = tableView.frame.size.width - CELL_SLIDE_WIDTH;
        } else {  // ending editing
            frame.origin.x = 0;
            frame.size.width = tableView.frame.size.width;
        }
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{ // match the tableView slide duration
            self.frame = frame;
        }];
    }
}
@end
```

If you have subviews that need to be anchored to the right of the cell (e.g., a button that should not slide), then do

```
mySubview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin; // anchors to the right margin
```

Also, you have to be creative when setting the subview's frame.origin.x.  I experimented with many values until I found something that worked (the value made no sense to me).